# ORA-30625 - JSON_OBJECT_T

Tags: json, plsql, oracle12c

I have the following procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetAddress(P_JSON_CLOB_IN IN CLOB, P_JSON_OBJECT_OUT OUT JSON_OBJECT_T) 
AS

V_JSON_OBJ JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T.parse(P_JSON_CLOB_IN);

V_ID CUSTOMERS.ID%TYPE;
V_TYPE ADDRESSES.TYPE%TYPE;

V_ADR ADDRESSES%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
 V_ID := V_JSON_OBJ.GET_STRING('id');
 V_TYPE := V_JSON_OBJ.GET_STRING('type');

 SELECT a.* INTO V_ADR FROM ADDRESSES a 
 INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS c ON c.ID=a.PEOPLEID
 WHERE c.ID = V_ID
 AND a.TYPE = V_TYPE;


 P_JSON_OBJECT_OUT.put('address1',TO_CHAR(V_ADR.ADDRESS1));
 P_JSON_OBJECT_OUT.put('address2',TO_CHAR(V_ADR.ADDRESS2));
 P_JSON_OBJECT_OUT.put('zipmask',TO_CHAR(V_ADR.ZIPMASK));
 P_JSON_OBJECT_OUT.put('city',TO_CHAR(V_ADR.CITY));
 P_JSON_OBJECT_OUT.put('countryCode',TO_CHAR(V_ADR.COUNTRYCODE)); 

 EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
   P_JSON_OBJECT_OUT.put('error','NO DATA FOUND');

END;
```

It compiles successfully, however when invoked returns oracle exception 
"ORA-30625 Method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed" on line 21.
I assume the error occurs because parameter P_JSON_OBJECT_OUT needs to be initialized prior to adding a key/value? How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the solution. Simply add the following line in the start of the block:

> P_JSON_OBJECT_OUT := new JSON_OBJECT_T;